# view.frame is not working in ipad?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am developing iPad application in landscape mode.I have set in all view controller  as  return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);.
but when I give change view frame through following code,it is not changing , it occupies full screen of ipad.How can i overcome this problem , any help please?I tried view.frame also.

```
 -(IBAction)category_Click:(id)sender
 {

CGRect rect = _categoryController.view.bounds;
rect.origin.x = 0;
rect.origin.y = rect.origin.y;
rect.size.width = 1024;
rect.size.height = 650;
_categoryController.view.bounds = rect;
_categoryController.view.bounds = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y,1024, 650);
[self presentModalViewController:_categoryController animated:YES];

 }
```

Comment: At first. You tell about `frame` but your code is about `bounds`.

Comment: i tried both..i have mentioned in my question?

Answer (score 0):

Check `modalPresentationStyle` property

```
_categoryController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
_categoryController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:_categoryController animated:YES];
_categoryController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 818, 739);
_categoryController.view.superview.center = self.view.center;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adjusting the frame *after* the viewController is presented?  I believe that the `presentModalViewController:animated:` method may sometimes alter the frame during its execution.  You may even need to wait until the animation is finished.

If it possible, perhaps try adjusting the view's frame in the '-(void)viewDidAppear:' method of the `_categoryController`'s class.

Generally, though, I have found that changing the appearance of a modal view controller in a smooth way is difficult.